# How to remove the "Run Code Cleanup" button from the bottom of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

That's the button on the bottom of Visual Studio on the (not extreme) left.

It looks like this:

[image]

It's there when a C# code file is shown.

Comment: @CodeCaster Accidentally clicking it can cause irreversible changes.

Comment: Can you right-click the status bar and select "Customize"?

Comment: Nothing is irreversible with proper version control, and doesn't Ctrl+Z allow to undo all changes it did? But I get your point, and it's a valid question.

Comment: @CodeCaster No. Can you? (And btw I don't have Resharper installed)

Comment: I can't at the moment, I'm on mobile and my laptop is too far away.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ctrl-Z doesn't work if you saved not noticing you clicked it. As for version control - why need to use that if there's a way to remove the button?

Comment: @CodeCaster What I meant is that there's no such thing. Right clicking doesn't give that option. Maybe you have Resharper and therefore have some functionality like that.

Comment: That's part of the "file health indicator". You can disable the whole thing but not just that button.  Tools > Options > Text Editor, uncheck "Show file health indicator"

Comment: @madreflection Thanks. That's good enough. You can transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster a) Thanks for weighing in. I now realize you were just pointing out that it's not completely irreversible. Thanks. b) You might be interested in the solution, see [one of the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709348/how-to-remove-the-run-code-cleanup-button-from-the-bottom-of-visual-studio#comment116179746_65709348).

Comment: Glad I could help, @ispiro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That button is part of the "file health indicator".  You can disable the whole feature but not just the button.

Go to **Tools > Options... > Text Editor** and uncheck the "Show file health indicator" option.

[image]

After disabling it, if you need something similar to the file health indicator, I suggest taking a look at the [Solution Error Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.SolutionErrorVisualizer) extension.